# Typescript reduce a list of objects to an object with a different shape

Tags: javascript, typescript

I cannot for the life of me work out how to modify the return value of reduce without a number of clunky type assertions. For example:

```js
const list: Array<Record<string, string | number>> = [
  {
    resourceName: "a",
    usage: 20
  },
  {
    resourceName: "b",
    usage: 50
  }
];

const toMap = list.reduce(
  (acc, item) => ({
    ...acc,
    [item.resourceName]: item.usage
  }),
  {}
);
```

`toMap` has the type `Record<string, string | number>` as `list` has the shape `Array<Record<string, string | number>>` but I don't care about the shape of my input list, I care about the shape of my output object, which is `Record<string, number>`.

In this example I could add a type assertion to the end to get the right type but there are times when the `list` type and output type don't match and having to use `as unknown as X` for an operation as common as `reduce` seems incorrect to say the least.

Comment: If you want the compiler to know that `item.usage` is a `number` then you can't widen `list`'s elements to `Record<string, string | number>`; otherwise `item.usage` is a `string | number`.  If you let the compiler infer the type of `list`, then you can do [either of these](//tsplay.dev/mbkLdW) to get the types you want, neither of which is a type assertion (the first is a generic type parameter specification, and the second is a type annotation; both are more type-safe than a type assertion).  If this meets your needs I can turn it into an answer. Otherwise, please let me know what's missing.

Comment: Very helpful. I've never really used Record types but I am dealing with objects with properties that change for every new month. What you are saying makes a lot of sense - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to care about the shape of the input list, at least to the extent that you want the compiler to understand that `item.usage` is a `number` and not a `string | number`.  If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `list` as `Array<Record<string, string | number>>`, then you're explicitly telling the compiler to forget everything about `list` except that it's an array of objects whose properties are of type `string | number`.  After this, any use of `reduce()` with `item.usage` would necessarily involve `string | number`, unless you employ something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to give the compiler back some of the information you threw away earlier.

In this case I'd recommend leaving off the type annotation for `list` and letting the compiler infer its type from the initialized value:

```
const list = [
  {
    resourceName: "a",
    usage: 20
  },
  {
    resourceName: "b",
    usage: 50
  }
];

/* const list: {
    resourceName: string;
    usage: number;
}[] */
```

You can see that this inferred type is an array of objects whose `resourceName` property is of type `string` and whose `usage` property is of type `number`.  This is a more useful classification of `list` for your purposes.

---

Now you want to use `reduce()`.  The issue here is that you are passing in an initial accumulator which is an empty object `{}`.  Left to its own devices, the compiler will infer `{}` as the type of this initial accumulator, and from there infer that the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter on the [`reduce()` call signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/24da242b673938e61669020d45d8aeccc301c186/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1386) is also of type `{}`, and finally conclude that the return value is of type `{}` as well.  (Sometimes the compiler's type inference gives you the types you want, and other times it doesn't.  That's just the way it goes with heuristics.) If you want something else to happen, you need to prevent this inference.

One way to do it is to declare the initial accumulator ahead of time with its type explicitly annotated to what you want:

```
const init: Record<string, number> = {};
const toMap = list.reduce(
  (acc, item) => ({
    ...acc,
    [item.resourceName]: item.usage
  }),
  init
);
// const toMap: Record<string, number>
```

Now the compiler does not need to infer the type of `init`; and the type parameter in `reduce()` is inferred to be `Record<string, number>`, and so `toMap` is also a `Record<string, number>`.

Another way to do it is to manually specify the type parameter when you call `reduce()`.  This prevents the inference of the type parameter, and allows the compiler to [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) infer the type of your initial accumulator  from it:

```
const toMap = list.reduce<Record<string, number>>(
  (acc, item) => ({
    ...acc,
    [item.resourceName]: item.usage
  }),
  {}
);
// const toMap: Record<string, number>
```

Either way should work for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2&ssl=24&ssc=39&pln=17&pc=1&strict=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gWAFAxgbxzzwCcBTCEAVxODIDkBDAWzIC4YAiRzgGiOJUIjAObsYAJgAMAgL79cBAaQrVaDFuM4AjPsphDR4gKwzFsnAF0A3DgD0AKhihIsRNA6FFKyjTpNWDmgSBDARW28DYTEOMCpmbTISCNl0SxgHOxxs7BdkKBAAWUYAB1R4JCgAOnIAEyo6AB4AJTJQElrG4NCRXhg4hKSAPiGACgFRxmBgPoQoMmYASlQhmFGvYhgq7amZ-XQ5hZrVPw1WSw5D5irDMTlFhTx8C2xFiLs7Z3B8otKOVvanW6YT6A0SJCGOTysFCc3+bRAHS6UBCIP68XBqzQzwi0JgBWKJQk5Xc1TqDTI40Uk2ms3mSxWaw2xG2VV2j2IB3px186gCZAuMCuN2iZHuHNhUBwb3snzxBNKEnhgORqN66MGEJwQA)